# How do i extract the message body from a mockendpoint in a java camel test?

Tags: java, apache-camel

This is a question on Java, camel. I have a route, in which I am trying to extract the message body from the vm:region endpoint, but get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds when i try to access the first index of the received exchanges, even though the expectedMessageCount of 1 is asserted. My route and code is shown below.

```
        from(uriMap.get("start_cDirect_2")).routeId("start_cDirect_2")
                .to(uriMap.get("cLog_2"))

                .id("cLog_2").choice().id("cMessageRouter_1").when()
                .simple("${in.header.type} == 'region'")

                .to(uriMap.get("vm:region_cMessagingEndpoint_2"))
                .id("cMessagingEndpoint_2").otherwise()

                .to(uriMap.get("vm:zipcode_cMessagingEndpoint_3"))
                .id("cMessagingEndpoint_3");
        from(uriMap.get("vm:start_cMessagingEndpoint_1"))
                .routeId("vm:start_cMessagingEndpoint_1")
                .to(uriMap.get("cLog_1"))

                .id("cLog_1").beanRef("beans.bean1").id("cBean_1")
                .to(uriMap.get("start_cDirect_2")).id("cDirect_1");
    }
```

My camel test in eclipse is as follows:

```
public class ShowUnitTestTest extends CamelTestSupport{
    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:vm:region")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;
    @Produce(uri = "vm:start")
    protected ProducerTemplate template; 
    @Override
    public String isMockEndpoints() {
        return "*";
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        ShowUnitTest route = new ShowUnitTest();
        route.initUriMap();
        return route;
    }

    @Test
    public void testRegionRouting() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint regionMock = getMockEndpoint("mock:vm:region");
        MockEndpoint zipcodeMock = getMockEndpoint("mock:vm:zipcode");

        regionMock.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        zipcodeMock.setExpectedMessageCount(0);

        // send a message with the region header
        sendBody("mock:log:cLog_1", "foo");
       template.sendBodyAndHeader("vm:start", "Foobar", "type", "region");

        // check the assertion
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();        
        Exchange exchange = regionMock.getExchanges().get(0);
        Message in = exchange.getIn();
        //try and print out the message body....
    }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might have made this a "comment" rather than an "answer" but I don't have sufficient reputation points on stack overflow. At any rate, conceptually there is not a problem (see my code below for a similar usage, which works in my tests). There must be some other glitch; have you stepped through it in a debugger?

```
// here the variable resultEndpointFtpCitationImages is a MockEndpoint in my junit test
byte[] bytesReceivedViaFtp = (byte[]) resultEndpointFtpCitationImages.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody();
```

Comment: I'm not sure why my assertion would pass and not be able to extract the exchange. I basically want to perform my own custom assertion on the body, but your answer helps a lot

Comment: Cool - in some of my tests I do more detailed checking/assertions on the body of the received message, so for sure you should be able to do that. There are also some methods on the MockEndpoint such as expectedBodyReceived (and similar) that might be of interest if you haven't already tried them. Unclear to me, as well, why your assertion is passing, but the exchanges collection is still empty, maybe one of the camel gurus will shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

(I would have commented, but don't have enough points either) Your assertion is satisfied because it does receive a message. What seems to be giving you trouble is that the body of the message is null, and not the message itself.